# why operator() function greater sort different container in different ways

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

if sort(A.begin(), A.end(), greater()) where A is vector, you get descending order for A; if priority_queue, greater > Q; you get ascending order for Q; I do not know why and it is hard to remember when to use > when to use < when writing my customized operator(). Here is my test code: can anybody tell how they are sorted?

```
struct compare_test{ //similar to greater() in STL
    bool operator()(const int a, const int b){ 
        return a>b;
    }
};    

void my_compare_test(){
vector<int> A;    
//  priority_queue<int,vector<int>, greater<int> > Q;         
priority_queue<int,vector<int>, compare_test > Q; 
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    A.push_back(i);
    Q.push(i);
}    
 // sort(A.begin(), A.end(), greater<int>());   
sort(A.begin(), A.end(), compare_test());   //get descending order
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "A = " << A[i] << "; "; 
}
cout << endl;
while(!Q.empty()){
    cout << "Q = " << Q.top() << "; ";  ////get ascending order
    Q.pop();
}
cout << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think of a priority queue as being sorted.  Just think of it as an abstract data type that always gives you fast access to the "greatest element".  Where "greatest element" is defined as the last element in a list containing the priority queue's data if the list was sorted using the same criteria that orders the priority queue.

Then there is no conflict. The same comparator does not in fact sort different containers in different ways, because a priority queue is not sorted.  It has an order, but it is not sorted.

Comment: +1 *don't think of a priority queue as being sorted* because it is not.

Comment: Thanks Ben, see my comment to Pete. I understand priority queue is not sorted. it is just a heap. I guess what you mean is for >, to eventually sort-heap as descending order. the priority queue need to construct min-heap. therefore when Q is popped, it poped in ascending order. right?

Comment: @user389955: No, that's not what I mean at all.  The fact that the elements pop off in ascending order if the priority queue is provided with `std::greater` as a comparator is just a side effect of its definition. What I mean is what I said in my answer.  Also, the priority queue being a heap is an implementation detail that is not defined in the standard.  It is the most obvious choice, but it need not be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start the other way around. When sorting a sequence using `<` you get the elements in ascending order. But a **priority** queue goes the other way, because its purpose is to give you the element with the **highest** priority. So if you think of the priority queue as a sorted sequence, the elements go from highest to lowest because that's what a priority queue does. When you use `>` instead, an ordinary sequence ends up sorted from highest to lowest, but a priority queue, because it goes the other way, ends up sorted from lowest to highest.

Comment: Thanks Pete. I don't understand ur reply: "But a priority queue goes the other way, because its purpose is to give you the element with the highest priority". Here is how I try to remember why a>b means descending ordering. To get descend ordering using priority queue, we need to construct min-heap, swap the minimum with the last element and repeatedly construct the queue with min-heap...; so by using a>b in operator() of priority Queue we get min-heap, that is why Q always pop() the min in the order of 0,1,2,3,4. Is it what you mean?

Comment: The key phrase is "if you think of a priority queue as a sorted sequence". That's not what a priority queue is for. If you want to think of it that way, expect to be confused.

Comment: I got it. in an array sorted in descending ordering, highest priority /greatest element means the last element which is minimum.